# What are the available options for Canvas initialisation in FabricJs?

Tags: fabricjs

`initialize` takes an "options" object according to the documentation [here](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#initialize)

However, it seems that the options object is not defined. I briefly searched the source code, but that didn't reveal anything.

Where can I get the definition of options object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `options` object as the second parameter of constructor as here:

```js
new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  width: 600,
  height: 600
})
```

Then when will invoke the `initialize` method all props in `options` object, in the end, will set to fabric canvas object. You can see it [here](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line513) in source code.

So, the definition of options object is all props and methods of fabric.Canvas. You can see them in source code below the `initialize` method, `uniScaleTransform`, `uniScaleKey`, `centeredScaling` etc. You can pass all of them to `options` object

Comment: Thanks. Just for clarification: do you really mean methods too? How would that work? Is the `set` method of a fabric class instance special, or does it just set an object's attribute? Incidentally, is there an easy way to list all the properties and methods of each class? In the docs you seem to have to scroll the whole page (making it difficult to get an overview).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. You can't rewrite the methods using `options` object. `set` is defined here https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/f30de19229c310414de03c68a144d1da884c31a1/dist/fabric.js#L576
And yes, I think in the doc you have to scroll the whole page.